# Git Manage Branches

Tags: git, gitlab

Estou querendo realizar uma gerência sobre os branches de novas funcionalidades.
Atualmente eu consigo ver pelo GitLab quantos commits o branch está a frente ou atrás do branch default do projeto.

No entanto gostaria de saber se o merge do branch default para o branch irá gerar algum conflito, isso para todos os branches do projeto.

Existe alguma ferramenta que fique avaliando os branches do projeto e já vai dando uma visão dos possíveis conflitos que poderão ocorrer com relação ao branch default do projeto?

Ou algum comando do git que possa me dar essa visão?

Resumindo é um projeto onde tem vários colaboradores, pelo gitlab eu já consigo ver os commits de cada branch que estão a frente ou atrás do branch default, o que eu preciso saber é se tem algum branch que estaria conflitando com o branch default.

Comment: Já deu um `git status` na branch ou master? Ele costuma dizer quantos commits vc está pra traz ou se alguém commitou algo

Comment: É um projeto onde tem vários colaboradores, pelo gitlab eu já consigo ver os commits de cada branch que estão a frente ou atrás do branch default, o que eu preciso saber é se tem algum branch que estaria conflitando com o branch default.

Comment: Uai, quando você der o merge ele vai te apontar que tem conflitos, dai é só resolve-los.

Comment: Mas eu quero a visão dos branches dos outros desenvolvedores, não vou ficar simulando Merge Request pra ficar vendo se os outros branches tem conflito ou não.

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas, qual o intuito de ficar olhando os branches dos desenvolvedores para saber se eles terão conflitos? Por tudo que eu vivenciei, isso é uma péssima prática. Uma prática muito melhor é usar o recurso de um VCS de terceira geração que permite que você faça o merge em último momento (_merge after commit_), diferentemente de um VCS de segunda geração (_merge before commit_)

Answer (score 1):

Nos projetos que eu trabalho, a gente abre Pull Request (usamos o github aqui, no GitLab acredito que seja [Merge Request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/add-merge-request.html)) para todo branch que tiver que ser mergeado com o master. Tendo o request, é possível ver se há conflitos e solicitar aprovação (code review) dos colegas.

Se o objetivo for apenas verificar se vai dar conflitos, tu não precisas confirmar a criação do request - dá para ver as modificações antes.

Comment: Eu precisava mesmo é de uma ferramenta que fosse me mostrando isso, hoje o projeto já tem 20 branches e uns 24 contribuidores.